# Shadow Content has wrong value

Tags: javascript, html

On my web page, every input field has a shadow content. As far as I know the shadow content is not explicitly inserted by me and I do not use it on the page otherwise.

My problem is that the values do not always match in the shadow content and input value;

so if i write the html

```html
<input class="value-input" type="number" id="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
```

in safari I can see a shadow content. and sometimes the shadow content has not the same value like the input value.

```html
<input class="value-input" type="number" id="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
  <div pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
    <div>
      <div contenteditable="plaintext-only">100</div>
    </div>
    <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button"></div>
  </div>
</input>
```

This wrong value cannot be caused by js, because I get the same problem if I disable js in the browser

Through this I get wrong values by read with js. In this case the console log gives me 100 instead of 1.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#number').value);
```

```html
<input class="value-input" type="number" id="number" data-minibasket-quantity-input="" value="1" min="1" max="10">
```

Does anyone have an idea how this number 100 comes into my shadow content, and why the shadow content doesn't have the same value like the input value?

I have found an input on the same page with this value (is the only one this value is found on the page)

```html
<input data-range-min="" data-value="2000" onpaste="return false" type="number">
  <div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
    <div id="editing-view-port">
      <div>2000</div>
    </div>
    <div pseudo="-webkit-inner-spin-button" id="spin">
    </div>
  </div>
</input>
```

It's possible the browser stores this value and set into next input number.
The problem only occurs on browser back

Comment: Hello Thomas, please explain your question, define the problem and share your full code to solve your problem. I suggest to read the article [How do I as a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, thank's for the tipps. I tried to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Just look on this example :

```
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>

<button class="search">Search (open browser console to see result)</button>

function searchURL() {
   let txt = searchTxt.value;
   console.log(txt);
   // window.location = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + txt; ...
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", ()=>searchURL());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/py2h3f47/
this is exacly what you are looking for.